# How to use shared global datasets in MPI?

Tags: c++, openmpi

I am an MPI beginner. I have a large array `gmat`  of numbers (type double, dimensions 1x14000000) which is precomputed and stored in a binary file. It will use approximately 100 MB in memory (14000000 x8 bytes /1024 /1024). I want to write a MPI code which will do some computation on this array (for example, multiply all elements of `gmat` by rank number of the process). This array `gmat` itself stays constant during run-time.
The code is supposed to be something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"
double* gmat;
long int imax;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
void performcomputation(int rank); // this function performs the computation and will be called by all processes

imax=atoi(argv[1]); // user inputs the length of gmat 

MPI::Init();
rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size(); //i will use -np 16 = 4 processors x 4 cores

if rank==0 // read the gmat array using one of the processes
{
gmat = new double[imax];
// read values of gmat from a file
// next line is supposed to broadcast values of gmat to all processes which will use it
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&gmat,imax,MPI::DOUBLE,1);     
}

MPI::COMM_WORLD.Barrier();
performcomputation(rank);  
MPI::Finalize();  

return 0;
} 

void performcomputation(int rank)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i <imax; i++)
cout << "the new value is" << gmat[i]*rank << endl; 
}
```

My question is when I run this code using 16 processes (-np 16), is the gmat same for all of them ? I mean, will the code use 16 x 100 MB in memory to store gmat for each process or will it use only 100 MB since I have defined gmat to be global ? And I don't want different processes to read gmat separately from the file, since reading so many numbers takes time. What is a better way to do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please do not use the MPI C++ bindings. These were deprecated in MPI-2.2 and then **deleted** in MPI-3.0 and therefore no longer part of the specification, which means that future MPI implementations are not even required to provide C++ bindings, and that if they do, they will probably diverge in the way the interface looks like.

That said, your code contains a very common mistake:

```
if rank==0 // read the gmat array using one of the processes
{
   gmat = new double[imax];
   // read values of gmat from a file
   // next line is supposed to broadcast values of gmat to all processes which will use it
   MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&gmat,imax,MPI::DOUBLE,1);     
}
```

This won't work as there are four errors here. First, `gmat` is only allocated at rank 0 and not allocated in the others ranks, which is not what you want. Second, you are giving `Bcast` the address of the pointer `gmat` and not the address of the data pointed by it (i.e. you should not use the `&` operator). You also broadcast from rank `0` but put `1` as the broadcast root argument. But the most important error is that `MPI_BCAST` is a collective communication call and **all** ranks are required to call it with the same value of the `root` argument in order for it to complete successfully. The correct code (using the C bindings instead of the C++ ones) is:

```
gmat = new double[imax];

if (rank == 0)
{
   // read values of gmat from a file
}
MPI_Bcast(gmat, imax, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//        ^^^^                   ^^^
//        no &                root == 0
```

Each rank has its own copy of `gmat`. Initially all values are different (e.g. random or all zeros, depends on the memory allocator). After the broadcast all copies will become identical to the copy of `gmat` at rank 0. After the call to `performcomputation()` each copy will be different again since each rank multiplies the elements of `gmat` with a different number. The answer to your question is: the code will use 100 MiB in *each rank*, therefore 16 x 100 MiB in total.

MPI deals with *distributed memory* - processes do not share variables, no matter if they are local or global ones. The only way to share data is to use MPI calls like point-to-point communication (e.g. `MPI_SEND` / `MPI_RECV`), collective calls (e.g. `MPI_BCAST`) or one-sided communication (e.g. `MPI_PUT` / `MPI_GET`).

Comment: thanks a ton :) was waiting for your reply. will keep your points in mind.